# Move block of orders in Account Dashboard

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

How I can move account My orders list in Account dashboard ? As My orders are on top at this time.

```
block block-dashboard-orders
```

what will be block name to move this ?

Comment: are you talking about sidebar which avilable in customer account?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya  No I am talking about account dashboard page where MY Recent orders and address books are

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it, so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block which is show recent order section on customer account page is `"customer_account_dashboard_top"`

The code of this block are avilable here.

```
app/design/frontend/[YOUR THEME]/layout/sales.xml

<customer_account_index>
        <!-- Mage_Sales -->
        <!--remove name="customer_account_dashboard_top"/-->
        <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
            <block type="sales/order_recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" template="sales/order/recent.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </customer_account_index>
```

And if you want to move that block at last then, you can do that by using phtml file.

```
app/design/frontend/[YOUT THEME]/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml
```

arround line no.33 there is code like this.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top') ?>
```

Move that code after this line.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info2') ?>
```

So now the order block is show at last.

Comment: I want to move it down . How can I ?

Comment: you want to move at where? at last?

Comment: I got this when I posted  this is reference container     1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type:

Comment: I update my answer, you can do that using phtml file. please check.

Comment: I dont have dashboard.phtml  in vendor or theme